# What is the unindented statement at the end of the python for loop?

Tags: python

When writing a for loop, there is always a statement at the end of the loop but outside the body of the loop, not indented inside the loop E.G; the print statement.

```
list=[]
for i in range(5):
    list.append(i+1)
print(list)
```

Why is the print statement outside the body of the for loop and not inside? How does this work, i could really use the clarification for something like this.

Comment: I recommend you try putting it in the loop block, the output will likely be the clearest explanation you can get

Comment: There isn't *always* a statement after the loop, it's just that all the examples you've seen look like that. It is outside and not inside because of the difference between "whistle while you work" and "whistle when you're done".

Comment: @molbdnilo That's a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list=[]
for i in range(5):
    list.append(i+1)
print(list)
```

result `[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
list=[]
for i in range(5):
    list.append(i+1)
    print(list)
```

result:

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is the difference. If you put print inside the loop it prints everytime the loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `print` inside the loop, it's going to print `list` during each iteration. If you have `print` outside, it'll print the full list after the loop has finished.